# Implementing interface/abstract with null/notnull properties

Tags: c#

So heres the situation. I've been thinking through how to do this. But I'm not super sure the best approach.

We have two data model classes that are used to create or update another data model class. Lets call them CreateUser and UpdateUser. and those are used to create/update the User class.

```
public class CreateUser
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string fullName { get; set; }
}

public class UpdateUser
{
    public int userId { get; set; }

    public string? username { get; set; }
    public string? password { get; set; }
    public string? email { get; set; }
    public string? fullName { get; set; }
}
```

I want the model from UpdateUser to share every attribute from the CreateUser model. But I want those attributes to be nullable. This is so you can do differential updates. This may seem trivial with the classes I'm providing. But in my use case we have very large classes and differential updates will perform better.

Currently we are maintaining these two classes separately. So when you make a change to CreateUser, You have to also go tweak UpdateUser as well. I would like to know if theres a better approach to this.

I've considered interfaces as a good option for this. But the problem is that I cannot define an interface with properties that can be nullable. They either are nullable or they arent. And I dont want my properties in CreateUser to be nullable. Those are required properties

```
public interface ICreateOrUpdateUser
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string fullName { get; set; }
}
```

in my example an interface like this would work. Because strings are nullable by default. But if we used an int instead, It breaks.

What I really need is the ability to create a blueprint for two classes that can be either nullable or not nullable.

Comment: Well, even with the `string` properties, it wouldn't really "work".  If you're using the `?` on strings, it implies you're using nullable reference types, and using your interface for the update version would be violating those rules since they can be null when you've stated in the interface that they cannot.  What you want isn't really possible as you're asking for a single contract to be valid for incompatible schemes (nullability).

Comment: Not sure you can solve this fully at compile time.  Might be better to have them inherit from the same class, and use validation during runtime depending on the type of operation being performed.

Comment: @Jonesopolis that is my best guess as well. I dislike it because from first read its immediately clear if a field is nullable that it is not necessary to provide that field. Whereas an external validator might be looked over when studying the model.

Maintaining double classes seems the best options but as our class gets larger I'm afraid things will slip through the cracks.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, strings are nullable (as you stated), so `string?` is redundant, but for the int case, there are a few options.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-6.0#Nulls

If you're trying to identify a state based model change (for instance, a create user model is different than all other states), you can document that in code by separating the interfaces for the states. This may be a better way of creating self-documenting code.

```cs
public interface IUser : IUserInitialization
{
    int? userId {get;set;}
}
public interface IUserInitialization
{
    string username { get; set; }
    string password { get; set; }
    string email { get; set; }
    string fullName { get; set; }
}
public class CreateUser : IUserInitialization
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string fullName { get; set; }
}

public class UpdateUser : IUser
{
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string fullName { get; set; }
}
```

I would recommend removing the nullable if possible, if you want to simplify, the following would match your case. In your CreateUser model, you can change the behaviour for the userId to always be null.

```cs
public interface IUser 
{
    int? userId {get;set;}
    string username { get; set; }
    string password { get; set; }
    string email { get; set; }
    string fullName { get; set; }
}
public class CreateUser : IUser
{
    public int? userId { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string fullName { get; set; }
}

public class UpdateUser : IUser
{
    public int? userId { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string fullName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is fine. But the issue is still pretty much the same in what you wrote. UpdateUser needs all fields to be nullable. no matter what the previous type is. This is so that when you make a call to UpdateUser you do not have to provide any field that isnt actually being updated. There are other ways to get around that issue but making them nullable makes it clear from the first read that you dont need it and thats what i want.

Comment: If you ensure all the fields are nullable, then you're fine. 
With CreateUser, using the getter/setter, use a private hidden backing field that is non-nullable and ignored on serialization. 

To provide a more specific example, we'd need more information on what you're trying to do.
In the second example, all fields of IUser are nullable.